# C#: Manage Azure SQL databases through Azure SDK in an Azure Function App

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-sdk

I want to check parameters of different SQL databases and servers on a regular basis by using a Function App. This Function App should use the Azure SDK to retrieve the required parameters from Azure. Unfortunately, it is hard to find a working sample for that. I found [this sample from MS on GitHub](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/sql-database-dotnet-manage-db) though.

So I tried to adapt it to my Function App like this:

```
    public void Run([TimerTrigger("0 30 * * * *", RunOnStartup = true)]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log, IAzure azure)
    {
        var list = azure.SqlServers.List();
    }
```

This does not work, of course as I need to somehow register the injected IAzure instance in my Startup.cs, this is the error message I get:

> Cannot bind parameter 'azure' to type IAzure. Make sure the parameter
> Type is supported by the binding. If you're using binding extensions
> (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called
> the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code
> (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(),
> builder.AddTimers(), etc.).

So the question would be what I need to register in my Startup.cs file to get this working?

I tried this:

```
        builder.Services.AddAzureClients(clientBuilder =>
        {
            clientBuilder.UseCredential(new DefaultAzureCredential());
        });
```

but it does not make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

- The reason you are getting this error is because you have not consumed the `IAzure`in the function so now you will have to consume the registered services in the time trigger using a constructor in your function.
- To consume the `IAzure`in the function just add a read only reference to it and then initialize it using a constructor.

```
        private readonly IAzure _azure;
        public Function1(IAzure azure)
        {
            this._azure = azure;
        }
```

- Now you can use `_azure` to execute your logic.
- Also, you will have to register the `IAzure` in the `startup.cs` file.

Here I add the above the code in a HTTP trigger (the code will not change for the Time trigger) and got the following output

[image]

Refer these [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#register-services) to use dependency injection in .NET Azure Functions and on how to register `IAzure` in startup.cs